# Excel VBA find webpage image and import it into excel

Tags: vba, excel, html, getelementsbytagname

Currently I am trying to search an open webpage for a number of png images and import them into different cells in a tab on my excel workbook.

My existing macro navigates a webpage which dictates what pictures will be showing and how many there are.

I am trying to write a macro to at this point search the open webpage and import the image to excel.

The number of images cannot be known each time the program is run. However each image is in the following html code:

```
img src="/files/exercises/31a_3 - trunk stability rotation kneex flexed.still002.194x146.png" title="Step 2"
```

While the file names will change. I am looking for all the images with the title="Step 2"

And import all these images to excel.
At the current moment I can successfuly find the urls by the following code:

```
max = 100
For i = 0 To max
For Each Elem In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("img")
If ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("img").Item(i).getAttribute("title") = "Step 2" Then
Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1") = "http://functionalmovement.com" & ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("img").Item(i).getAttribute("src")
Exit For
Exit For
End If
Next
Next
End Sub
```

Issues:

1. How can I search the entire page and have the first found put in a specific cell, the second found put in another cell and so on until no more are found.
2. Is there a way to have the image itself appear now that the full url is known for each image.

Answer (score 0):

Found what I was looking for. This code searches for images with title="Step 1". I then download these images.

```
Sub findimageA()

Dim strURL As String
Dim ie As Object
Dim Elem
Dim X

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
strURL = "http://blahblah"
ie.Navigate strURL
ie.Visible = True
Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> 4)
    DoEvents
Loop
For Each Elem In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("img")
    If Elem.getAttribute("title") = "Step 1" Then
        Select Case X
            Case Is = 0
            pic1aURL = "http://functionalmovement.com" & Elem.getAttribute("src")
            pic1aName = Elem.getAttribute("src")
            pic1aName1 = Replace(pic1aName, "/files/exercises/", "")
            Case Is = 1
            pic2aURL = "http://functionalmovement.com" & Elem.getAttribute("src")
            pic2aName = Elem.getAttribute("src")
            pic2aName1 = Replace(pic2aName, "/files/exercises/", "")
            Case Is = 2
        End Select
        X = X + 1
    End If
Next
     If Not IsEmpty(picaName) Then
          DownloadFile
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: My new process searches for all images with the title name then dowloads the image.

From here I will creat a sub to insert picture from file